# Query SQL - two instructions for return in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two instructions and I need that an instruction of SQL return in 2 columns.

```
Column 1: Subfolders.
Column 2: Main folders of this subfolders.
```

--MainFolders

```
select distinct folder_path as 'main_folder' 
from X
where folder_path like '%\' order by folder_path
```

--Return 6 rows

--SubFolders

```
select distinct folder_path as 'sub_folder'
from X
where folder_path not like '%\' order by folder_path
```

--Return 14 rows

Comment: I imagine `X` in both cases is a different folder. Additionally, your code is missing necessary information to understand this question. It needs to be made clearer. For example, both your queries use `older_path like '%\' order by folder_path`. How does that work?

Comment: @meewoK:  OP has `like` for main and `not like` for sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you basically want a `JOIN`.  Assuming your main look like `folder1\`, `folder2\`, and your sub look like `folder1\a`, `folder1\b`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    main.folder_path AS main_folder,
    sub.folder_path AS sub_folder
FROM
    X main
    JOIN X sub
        ON main.folder_path = LEFT(sub.folder_path, LEN(main.folder_path))
```

Comment: Nice catch! The whole not like and like thing escaped me.

Comment: Tks, Zimdanen and all! All is ok! I just made one adaptation. I add an "where" in this instruction. "where main.folder_path <> sub.folder_path".